# Firebase Notificationでアプリが強制停止された場合でもpush通知を受け取れるようにするにはどうしたらよいか

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase ConsoleのNotificationタブからメッセージを作成して送信を行い、メッセージが受信できることを確認しました。
送信するメッセージは、メッセージ文とラベルを指定し、ターゲットをユーザセグメントにしています。
https://gyazo.com/a0d5dd07be0f31e1b3f6da7f0bd56158

ドキュメントにある通り、

- アプリがforegroundにある場合（Activityが表示されている）
- アプリがbackgroundにある場合（ホームボタンを押してActivityが非表示になった状態）

のとき受信ができました。
しかし、アプリを強制停止した場合、通知が受信されません。
（強制停止は端末の設定→該当のアプリ→強制停止で行いました）
その際logcatには以下のエラーメッセージが表示されています。

`W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=jp.gcreate.sample.samplefirebasenotification  (has extras) }`

アプリが強制終了されたとしても通知を受け取れるようにするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="jp.gcreate.sample.samplefirebasenotification"
    >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

FirebaseMessagingServiceを拡張したクラス

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessage";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder      = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setContentText(notification.getBody())
                   .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                   .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            managerCompat.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 英語版のSOに、似た質問と解決方法のアイディアがあります。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t　ただし、これはユーザ操作による強制停止を阻害する事になるので、おすすめしません。

Answer (score 2):

端末は何を使ってますか？
Huaweiなど一部の端末では保護されたアプリでないと通知を表示しません。

> 設定＞詳細設定＞バッテリーマネージャー＞保護されたアプリ